# How to locate the element inside the <p> tags?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a few elements inside this kind of tag as below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNj55.png)

How do I locate these kinds of elements

I tried to locate the foresaid element, which the Selenium C# is not working

Comment: What exactly have you tried? What errors faced? Share your code trials

Answer (score 1):

You can use xpath to locate the p element:

```
//div[@data-testid='patientLink']/p
```

Later you can call the getText() of the element located by the above selector.

Comment: I tried locating with data-test-id but the selenium did not locate, I anyways asked the dev to add an ID to the elements, so that solved the issue,

Answer (score 0):

give the p tag you are looking for an id. Then lookup the element using

```
var driver = //whatever your driver is;

driver.FindElement(By.Id("element-id-goes-here"));
```